# ¿No sería mejor abrir una nueva pestaña en vez de cargar enlaces en la misma página?

Tags: característica-nueva, interfaz-de-usuario

Desde que empecé a colaborar en SOes he visto y no sé si el único que cree que es molesto:

Cuando uno hace clic a cualquier enlace (como este que lleva a [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions)) siempre se abre en la misma pestaña que utilizo en el navegador. No sé si seré el único que prefiera que se abra una nueva pestaña en vez de que sea en la misma, puesto que a mi parecer, redireccionarme a otro sitio me "corta" el rollo con la pregunta.

En caso de que sea solo un *capricho mío*, ¿alguna vez se consideró algo así? Si se consideró, quisiera saber la razón por la que abrir una nueva pestaña no es viable.

Comment: deberiamos chequear en meta stack exchange.. creo que ha sido el comportamiento por defecto desde siempre...

Comment: entiendo, pero, ¿no es momento del cambio?

Comment: Puede ser una caracteristica a añadir,pero yo no lo hecho en falta ya que estoy acostumbrado a pinchar los enlaces con el boton medio del ratón,lo que siempre te abre en una nueva pestaña.

Comment: Yo no tengo botón medio del ratón, y pues aveces dar el clic derecho y nueva pestaña se me va de la cabeza

Comment: Nunca me había fijado, creo que yo uso comand+clic en automático O.o

Comment: Creo que la gran mayoría siempre abrimos en nueva ventana, pero nunca falta la vez que se te va y te carga en la misma pestaña

Comment: igual desconozco si esto se puede cambiar a nivel de sitio o va a toda la red...

Comment: También puedes usar Ctrl+click para abrir en otra pestaña. La verdad, yo prefiero que esté en la misma pestaña para que así sea opcional abrirlo en una nueva. Si se abriera por defecto en una nueva, acabaría con tropecientas pestañas cada día.

Comment: Cuando digo "boton medio del ratón" me refiero a pulsar en la rueda de desplazamiento,yo creo que en practicamente todos los ratones actuales la rueda de desplazamiento es ademas un botón. Pulsando en ella, el enlace se abre en otra ventana (y si vamos a eso, pulsando ahi en las pestañas superiores se cierra)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hubo un tiempo en el que se debatió mucho sobre ese tema, no en Stackoverflow sino en internet en general, sobre todo cuando muchos navegadores no tenían pestañas y se abría una nueva ventana. Normalmente se abrían en la misma ventana los enlaces internos y los que externos en una nueva para que el visitante no abandonara tu página (aunque a veces se usaba en todos los enlaces y acababas con 20 ventanas abiertas), todavía muchos usan ese criterio.

Para mí y para otros lo más importante es intentar siempre que sea posible dar al usuario el control de sus acciones, si al pulsar un enlace se me abre en  una nueva  pestaña no puedo elegir, en cambio si es en la misma pestaña yo puedo decidir también abrir en una nueva.

Abrir en una nueva pestaña por defecto anula la funcionalidad del botón atrás, lo que para algunos usuarios puede ser frustrante si suelen usar esta característica. Hay muchas razones por la que no desees que se te abran pestañas: quiza navegas desde un movil y te resulta incómodo, o tu equipo tiene poca RAM y se te bloquee con muchas pestañas, etc.

En resumen, dejar elegir al usuario creo que compensa las pequeñas molestias que pueda ocasionar a los que prefieren abrir siempre en una nueva pestaña.

Comment: creo que es la respuesta que estaba buscando, gracias

Comment: @L.Ronquillo En tal caso por favor considera la posibilidad de pulsar en la señal verde que permite (bajo los votos) que permite marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: listo, estaba esperando a ver si alguien me daba otra respuesta, gracias amigo :)

Comment: Algo triste es que no se permite en los enlaces poner `target="_blank"` siendo que se permite la etiqueta html `<a>` tanto en comentarios como en preguntas/respuestas  (jeje si, me quería pasar de listo )